# Using TRRS headset as a microphone through Mic In?

Tags: cable, headphones

Say I have a pair of headphones (headphones only, TRS) and a headset (sound and mic, TRRS).

Can I plug the headset into the Mic In 3.5mm port and use it as a microphone, while using the other pair of headphones to listen to sounds?

Comment: Just Google '3.5mm trrs to trs splitter adapter'

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm just trying to see if I can get by with the hardware I have, without any extra accessories.

Comment: maybe try [AudioSwitcher](http://audioswit.ch/er) & see if it can persuade both to work at once.